# Using Bind in an asynchronous context

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I'm using the `language-ext' package for C# in an attempt to make our code more robust, but struggling on how to chain async operations.

Consider the following abstract example of a simple class describing a vehicle

```
public class MyVehicle
{
    public MyVehicle(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public MyVehicle DeepCopy()
    {
        return new MyVehicle(Name);
    }
}
```

and another class to store some state about a vehicle

```
public class MyVehicleState
{
    public MyVehicle CopiedVehicle { get; private set; }

    public Option<int> EditingId { get; set; }

    public void SetCopiedVehicle(MyVehicle vehicle)
    {
        CopiedVehicle = vehicle;
    }
}
```

and a vehicle repository to retrieve vehicles

```
public class MyVehicleRepository
{
    public Option<MyVehicle> GetVehicle(int id)
    {
        return id == 2 ? Some(new MyVehicle("Delorian")) : Option<MyVehicle>.None;
    }
}
```

If I want to set the copied vehicle property in `MyVehicleState` to be a deep copy of that defined by `SelectedVehicleId` in the same class, I could do the following (not sure if correct):

```
    var state = new MyVehicleState
    {
        EditingId = Some(2)
    };
    var repo = new MyVehicleRepository();

    state.EditingId
        .Bind(vehicleId => repo.GetVehicle(vehicleId))
        .Map(vehicle => vehicle.DeepCopy())
        .IfSome(copiedVehicle => state.SetCopiedVehicle(copiedVehicle));
```

Now, what if I change the vehicle repository to be asynchronous, such that

```
public class MyVehicleRepository
{
    public async Task<Option<MyVehicle>> GetVehicle(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        return id == 2 ? Some(new MyVehicle("Delorian")) : Option<MyVehicle>.None;
    }
}
```

How do I update my functional code to do the same thing and set the deep copy in my state class?

I've tried swapping to `BindAsync` and using `MapAsync`, but I seem to end up with an input I need to unwrap twice and not sure how to proceed (N.B. new to this functional world).

**Update**

The following seems to work, but is it the most succinct way?

```
await state.EditingId
        .MapAsync(async vehicleId => await repo.GetVehicle(vehicleId))
        .IfSome(x => x
            .Map(y => y.DeepCopy())
            .IfSome(z => state.SetCopiedVehicle(z)));
```

Comment: Do you want the surrounding method to also become async? Or stay sync and block on repo retrieval?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged F#?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yes, I'd like to await the whole functional chain (will remove the F# tag)

Comment: `.MapAsync(async vehicleId => await repo.GetVehicle(vehicleId))` looks like the right solution to me (I was going to write an answer to suggest exactly this!)

Comment: @JohnWu - and there's no way to 'flatten' the nested operation that comes after `MapAsync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flatten a [functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors), then use [monadic](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/03/28/monads) bind.

This is the simplest alternative I could come up with:

```
await state.EditingId
    .BindAsync(i => repo.GetVehicle(i).ToAsync())
    .Map(v => v.DeepCopy())
    .Iter(state.SetCopiedVehicle);
```

The [ToAsync](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Option/Option/index.html#OptionAsyncExtensions_0_ToAsync_1) conversion is necessary because it converts `Task<Option<MyVehicle>>` to `OptionAsync<MyVehicle>`, off which the subsequent `Map` and `Iter` hang.

Comment: Opening up a new world :) - the answer now has me asking whether a method should return `Task<Option<T>>` as in `MyVehicleRespository` or whether these methods ought to return `OptionAsync<T>` straight off the bat? Not sure how the latter would be constructed, I presume just with `ToAsync()` again...

Comment: @JamesB Both `Task<Option<T>>` and `OptionAsync<T>` are useful, as you'll probably find with experience. One thing to consider, though, is that `OptionAsync<T>` requires an explicit dependency on LanguageExt, whereas `Task<Option<T>>` is plain vanilla C#. Depending on how widely reusable you want your API to be, that should influence your decision, too.